# Noise generated by monitor from Word document

Tags: noise, adapter, monitor

I was zooming in and out of Word documents of only text and noticed that a noise was produced. The noise increased in pitch as I zoomed out and decreased as I zoomed in. I tried changing the font colour and the same noise was heard.

I thought it had something to do with the contrast of the font colour and the white background, so I created the following checkerboard pattern and zoomed in and out of it and was unable to produce the noise:

[image: Checkerboard pattern]

I have a 2014 MacBook Air which is connected to a HP Z22i monitor.

My adapter setup is as follows:
Thunderbolt (non-genuine adapter) -> HDMI -> DVI

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lNlAMhBKdliZ5Ony-rJ8N6bYtixk3HjG/view?usp=sharing) is a link to a video of a Word document being zoomed in and out of. You may have to turn up the volume, it is fairly quiet.

Would you know what is causing the noise and why it increases in pitch as there is a greater percentage of white shown?

Comment: Where is the sound coming from? The motherboard, the speakers or the monitor?

Comment: The noise is coming from the monitor. The monitor does not have speakers and I can hear the noise from all parts of the screen.

Comment: Typically in electronic devices coils vibrate due changing magnetic fields. Localizing the sound is difficult because the sound in the air can be radiated by everything which has mechanical contact with the vibrating part. I guess the vibrating part cannot be found by watching videos or doing something else outside your monitor. In the past sounds predicted troubles because some soldering joints broke due the tearing of the metal.